# What is the better way of getting concatenated rows from a child table in a query?

Tags: mysql, database, join

For my college project I am doing a model e-commerce website for learning. I have searched for similar questions, however I am unable to get deeper ideas.

My current tables structure:

1. Products - sku(PK), name, price, other_columns
2. ProductMedia - path(UNIQUE), product_sku (from products table).

The `path` contains the filename of the media.

When I retrieve a product data, I select the columns from table: products and LEFT JOIN productMedia and GROUP_CONCAT and get the paths.

**Query:**

```
SELECT
p.*, // for simplicity mentioned as *
(GROUP_CONCAT(path SEPARATOR ',') FROM productMedia WHERE product_sku = p.sku) as product_images
FROM products p
WHERE SOME_CONDITION // Single or multiple conditions associated with table products alone
```

To display, I `explode` the product_images and loop to display or use it for other purposes.

Now my questions are:

1. Is this efficient approach? Or any better approach which I am unaware of?
2. When multiple columns need to be concatenated from the child table (here productMedia), I am writing `GROUP_CONCAT (column SEPARATOR) as concatenatedColumn` multiple times, will this not affect the performance?

Some production example queries,

```
SELECT
    p.name, p.sku, p.mrp, p.selling_price,
    (GROUP_CONCAT(path SEPARATOR ',') FROM productMedia WHERE product_sku = p.sku) as product_images
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.category = 'books'
```

---

```
SELECT
p.name, p.sku, p.mrp, p.selling_price,
(GROUP_CONCAT(path SEPARATOR ',') FROM productMedia WHERE product_sku = p.sku) as product_images
FROM products p
WHERE p.selling_price < 1000 AND p.category = 'toys'
```

Comment: Can you supply the actual code you're using and some example data so it's easier to get a grip of what you want to achieve in terms of performance?

Comment: You are missing part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try not to use GROUP_CONCAT() to fetch child rows like the scenario you describe.

I would do this simpler query:

```
SELECT p.*, m.* // really write out the columns, don't use * 
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN productMedia m ON m.product_sku = p.sk
WHERE <conditions on p>
```

This query is easier to write and easier to optimize.

It does return a variable number of rows for each p, because you may have 0, 1, or many matching rows in productMedia. The values of `p.*` will be duplicated for every matching row of `m`. It's not hard to process that in your application code as you fetch the rows.

Comment: Yes, I agree. On production I will not be using *. Here for making the question little easier to understand I put as *.

Answer (score 0):

Formally (dependent by `SOME_CONDITION` this conditions must be placed to WHERE, HAVING or both - so I cannot insert such a generic placeholder into the query without conditions clarification):

```
SELECT p.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pm.path SEPARATOR ',') paths
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductMedia pm ON p.sku = pm.product_sku
GROUP BY p.sku;
```

If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled you'll get an error. This query is safe for partial grouping, so I'd recommend to alter session SQL Mode for this query (all 3 queries must be executed in the same connection strongly! the best way is to execute them in one multi-query statement):

```
SET @@sql_mode := REPLACE((@old_sql_mode := @@sql_mode), 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '');
SELECT p.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pm.path SEPARATOR ',') paths
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN ProductMedia pm ON p.sku = pm.product_sku
GROUP BY p.sku;
SET @@sql_mode := @old_sql_mode;
```

If there is no matched record in `ProductMedia` you'll get NULL for such product. If NULL is not safe for you, use `COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(pm.path SEPARATOR ','), '') paths` instead.

> Is this efficient approach? Or any better approach which I am unaware of?

Yes, it is efficient enough. Of course, you may select one path per record (and obtain a lot of `p.*` fields values duplicates) - this will slightly decrease the amount of work for PHP but increase data transter and memory usage size. Additionally in my approach you do not need in additional output recordset pre-sorting by `p.sku`.

> When multiple columns need to be concatenated from the child table (here productMedia), I am writing `GROUP_CONCAT(column SEPARATOR) as concatenatedColumn` multiple times

You may use both separate GROUP_CONCAT for each field, or concatenate everything into one value, like

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', field1, field2,...) SEPARATOR ',')
```

You may use both the same separator (then explode and iterate over one array) and different separators (and explode by records, then explode each record value by fields).

> will this not affect the performance?

But you need in this data? so no way, you must do...

And "the difference in performance" - while compare with what?